# how different browser perform when copying and pasting alt text in the img tag?

Tags: html, image

How can I make the img tag perform the same when user copy and paste the img tag in different browser. As most of you guys know, the img tag have the alt attribute and text attribute. When you display the img tag, you could show the text message when user hover over the image by using these two attribute.

But the problem I'm facing is different browser perform differently when user want to copy the image. Some browser like firefox(3.6.X or up) could convert the image into text, and most of other browser it seems do not support that feature.

How can I make the img tag perform the same when user copy and paste in different browsers?

you could go to the following link for further reference.

http://rebuildingtheweb.com/en/how-browsers-export-alt-text/

Comment: Paste where and in what format - HTML, text, RTF? Copy how - directly from the document? I don't understand. Can you give an example?

Comment: You aren't going to have much luck changing this behavior on your end. It's a built-in feature of the browser.

Comment: @Pekka paste into excel or text editor.. it seems only show the alt text message if copy and paste from firefox.. :(

Comment: @Nathan Taylor yes.. but is there any way I can accomplish the same result? thanks for your feedback..

Comment: very hardly I think. This is outside your control

Answer (score 0):

At the very least, you should report this as a bug to WebKit (i.e.: Chrome and Safari) here: http://webkit.org/quality/reporting.html